# Connect Google Container Builder to github

Tags: github, google-cloud-platform

I want to use Google Container Builder to build a container from github. I follow the directions from [here](https://cloud.google.com/container-builder/docs/how-to/build-triggers). When I connect to github, it gives me a long list of the repo's I can use. It includes repos in my account and in organizations where I have owner rights. It omits one particular organization, even though I have owner rights on those repos, too.

I tried listing the repo's with this command:

```
curl --silent -u rscohn2:xxx https://api.github.com/user/repos?per_page=100\&page=1 | grep full_name
```

and again for page=2. This listing matches the list that GCP presents, except it also include the missing repo's. I get the same list from github when I use Source Repositories. I tried logging out of github so it logs in again. I cannot see what is special about the missing repo's to make GCP omit them. Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/clahub/clahub/issues/64#issuecomment-58761756 and below?